# Bring non-realised ListViewItem into view

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollviewer

I've got a ListView which is empty in the beginning. Then I continuously add items to the ListView. At some point, all items fill the whole available room and from there I'd like to scroll the ListView to the item that has just been added.

In general, this can be accomplished by calling `ListViewItem.BringIntoView` or `ListView.ScrollIntoView(ListViewItem)`.

However, the ListView is bound to a ListCollectionView and the Source of that is an ObservableCollection of ViewModel items. So, I'm adding ViewModel-items to that collection. The View-item is then created through the binding.

As the item is outside of the visible area, the ListViewItem is not created right away, much less realised. If the scroll view is close to the bottom of the ListView, the ListViewItem will be created and realised shortly after.<sup>1</sup>
If the scroll view is somewhere in the middle of the ListView, it won't work at all.

Setting `IsVirtualizing` to false would fix the issue because the item is then created and realised anyway. But this has obviously has some performance downsides.

So, I'm trying to find a way so that the item that has just been added to the collection is created and realised and, ultimately, can be brought into view.

Does any one have an idea how to approach this issue?

---

<sup>1</sup> If the scroll view is closed to the bottom, it basically works but has a weird behavior where it appears that only every other ListViewItem is brought into view.

Comment: How do you add new Items? What are their types? I mean are they string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VirtualizationPanel has a method [BringIndexIntoViewPublic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.bringindexintoviewpublic(v=vs.110).aspx) which generates the item and makes it visible.

Here's an example with all relevant code.

```
public class ListView_ViewModel
{
  private CollectionViewSource _collectionViewSource;
  private ObservableCollection<ListViewItem_ViewModel> _listViewItemViewModels;
  private ListView _listView;

  private void AddItem()
  {
    var newListViewItemViewModel = new ListViewItem_ViewModel();
    _listViewItemViewModels.Add(newListViewItemViewModel);
    var indexOfNewItem = _collectionViewSource.View.Cast<ListViewItem_ViewModel>()
                           .ToList().IndexOf(newListViewItemViewModel);
    var virtualizingPanel = VisualTreeHelper.FindChild<VirtualizingPanel>(_listView);
    virtualizingPanel.BringIndexIntoViewPublic(indexOfNewItem);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell the exact problem based on your question. However, it might be because of the behavior of `Equals` function. Consider this structure:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button Name="addItem" Click="addItem_Click" Content="Add new and scroll" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
    <ListView Name="sv" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    </ListView> 
</DockPanel>
```

There is button that tries to add new Items and scroll to the end.

It will work if you add items that are not the same:

```
private void addItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sv.ItemsSource == null)
        sv.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    string newitem = "new item" + (sv.Items.Count + 1).ToString();
    ((ObservableCollection<string>)sv.ItemsSource).Add(newitem);
    sv.ScrollIntoView(newitem);
}
```

Note that the strings are never equal (see `(sv.Items.Count + 1).ToString()` part). However, this will not work:

```
private void addItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sv.ItemsSource == null)
        sv.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    string newitem = "new item";
    ((ObservableCollection<string>)sv.ItemsSource).Add(newitem);
    sv.ScrollIntoView(newitem);
}
```

since `Equals` returns the first item.

Comment: That's interesting. I copied your code and could verify that I'm seeing the same behavior. However, in my case I'm adding "new ListViewItem" and this seems to make a difference. I've just set up a test program where I add "new ListViewItem()" in a for loop. With "item.BringIntoView" it doesn't work. With "ListView.ScrollIntoView(item)" it works fine in my test program. This is certainly different to what I'm seeing in the actual program. But I didn't think that that would make any difference.

Comment: I check the code with ``ListViewItem`` and works. You should post your code for further help.

Comment: I could fix it by setting "VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"". I didn't think about this before. Anyway, I will have to dig into this further. I haven't fully understood what's really going on here. Thank you all the same.

Comment: As of my latest findings I updated the question to describe the issue in more detail. I'm afraid, however, that this makes your answer obsolete now.